# Calculate SUM in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php

 $today=date('Y-m-d');
  $sorgu = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM urun");
  while ($sira = mysqli_fetch_array($sorgu)) {
  $urun = $sira['urun'];

  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT product_name, birim, SUM(quantity) FROM 
  product WHERE product_name = '$urun' AND quantity != '0' AND quantity > '0' 
  AND grup!='uygulama' AND skt > '$today' GROUP BY product_name, birim ");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  if ($row['2'] <= $sira['minstok']) {

  echo count($row['0']);

} } } ?>
```

This code belongs to a table which has a notification system. I want the notification part increase when the line number increases in that table but it turns 11111111... , So how can I make the code give me sum?

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output

Comment: Look at your code. Think what it does. Where do you output and what. Why is it that way. How to do counting. Go line by line in your head.

Comment: I doubt that `$row[0]` is __array__. So, it's `count()` always will be __1__.

Comment: Explain your problem step-by-step, yet keeping it precise.

Comment: This code belongs to a table which has a notification system. I want the notification part increase when the line number increases in that table but it turns 11111111... , So how can I make the code give me sum? Sorry

Comment: It's great that you want the notification part to increase, but this is not PsychicsOverflow and we have no idea what the table looks like, what data is in the table and the HTML is a mystery to us. Read [ask], and create  a [mcve]. Until then - Voted to close as unclear

Comment: Oh dear. See about JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incidentally, everything up to `while ($row...` can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT p.product_name
     , p.birim
     , SUM(p.quantity) total 
  FROM urun u
  JOIN product p
    ON p.product_name = u.urun
   AND p.quantity > 0
   AND p.grup != 'uygulama' 
   AND p.skt > CURDATE()
 GROUP 
    BY p.product_name
     , p.birim;
```